# I can not use manipulated data in EasyQuery?

Tags: easyquery

1. Suppose I have 4 columns. I want write query as 
   Select Name,Age,DOB,'' as Salary;
   I am not able to write ('' as Salary) in easy query?
2. Also I am not able to use union in easy query?
3. How to write sub query in Select statement?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - did you mean EasyQuery by Korzh.com (https://korzh.com/easyquery)? If so - why don't you contact their support team first?

2. As far as I know:

   - you can set a title for each column right in Columns Panel widget
   - there is no way to create UNION queries using EasyQuery UI directly. But you can create two separate queries and concatenate them
   - You can define a virtual attribute (field) with sub-query statement in its expression and then use that new attribute the same way as any other in your model